# Advanced Custom Fields - Storing array value for further usage

Tags: posts, php

This might might be more of a PHP question - but does deal with a WordPress plugin, Advanced Custom Fields

I am using a global select option to store a specific Location (custom post type) as the headquarters. I am storing the value as such:

```
function options_headquarters() {
    foreach(get_field('option_headquarters','options') as $post_object) {
        $options_headquarters = $post_object->ID;
        return $options_headquarters;
    }
}
```

What I am fuzzy on is - since my option is only allowed to grab one value -- is there an alternative to using a foreach statement (to grab just a specific array value) and still applying it to the post_object?

That function stores the postID of that Location. I am currently outputting this in my template as:

```
echo get_field('location_phone',options_headquarters());
```

which grabs a field called `location_phone` (a meta value within the Location custom post type) and specify a specific postID to grab the value from (the headquarters). Is there a better way of handling passing in this headquarters value? Just pulling this out of you know where, but something like `options_headquarters('location_phone');` would be pretty sweet ;)

Thanks!

Comment: function options_headquarters() {
      $headquarters_field = get_field('option_headquarters','options');
      $headquarters = isset($headquarters_field[0]) ? $headquarters_field[0]->ID : NULL;
      return $headquarters;
    }

Did it for me :)

Comment: Zach, please add the solution as an *Answer* and mark it solved, so it gets out of the *Unanswered* category...

Comment: Cool! One last thing: in the Q, when you say *"[...]using a global select option to store a specific CPT [...]*, do you mean **"...using a Post Object Field Type..."**? . . . [Snapshot](http://i.imgur.com/SmX8p.png).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This ended up working for me:

```
function options_headquarters() { 
    $headquarters_field = get_field('option_headquarters','options'); 
    $headquarters = isset($headquarters_field[0]) ? $headquarters_field[0]->ID : NULL; 
    return $headquarters; 
}
```